# What are the sunnah rakahs of taraweeh?

Tags: taraweeh

In some mosques rakahs of taraweeh prayer are 8 and in some 20. So, what are the sunnah rakahs of taraweeh (8 or 20) ?

Comment: 8 or 10 if we consider it the same as the night prayer of the Prophet pbuh, or more 20 following some madhabs (+2 shaf'a and 1 witr) up to 36 following an opinion of the maliki school.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to the decision of the individual worshipper based on his school of thought called in Arabic Madhhab.

A Muslim strictly following Hanafi or Shafi school of thought would pray 20 Rakah

It is not wrong or a sin to pray 8 Rakah or increase it to 20 Rakah

these are trivialities in religion

God looks at the intentions and sincerity and God consciousness(Taqwa) of the individual not e quantity of his worship  in judging His slave